# Clean up Chroot

Tags: chroot, reset

Is there way to quickly clean up or revert your chroot to its previous new state, without reinstalling or re setting it up, so I could start fresh again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `schroot` supports LVM and Btrfs snapshots. From its man page:

> **Source chroots**
>          Some  chroot types, for example LVM snapshots and Btrfs snapshots, provide session-managed copy-on-write snapshots of the chroot.  These also provide a source chroot to allow easy access to the filesystem used as a source for snapshotting.  These are regular chroots as well, just  with  the snapshotting disabled.  For a chroot named "sid-snapshot" (i.e. with a fully qualified name of "chroot:sid-snapshot"), there will also be a corresponding source chroot named "source:sid-snapshot".  Earlier versions of schroot provided source chroots with a '-source' suffix.
>   These are  also provided  for  compatibility.  In this example, this would be called "chroot:sid-snapshot-source".  These compatibility names will be dropped in a future version, so programs and scripts should switch to using the namespace-qualified names rather than the old suffix.

Otherwise you can look at other copy-on-write filesystems (in short COW), as `copyfs`, `cowdancer`.